# ChartJS Line chart causes browser crash

Tags: angularjs, browser, crash, chart.js

I am updating a Line chart using HTTP get through ngResource and a rest API. 
My technique is to get the JSON dataset and create a new chart every time a user is clicking on a button.
It works great, but at one time, it causes the browser crash. I have tested on Chrome, Firefox on both Windows and Linux.

In my controller :

```
$scope.labels = $scope.dataFromREST;
$scope.series = ['Series A'];
$scope.data = [$scope.dataFromREST2];
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
    console.log(points, evt);
};
$scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }];
$scope.options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
                id: 'y-axis-1',
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
                position: 'left'

            }
        ],
        xAxes: [{
            responsive: true,
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 20
            }
        }]

    }

};
```

In my index.html :

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
                    chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
                    chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
            </canvas>
```

Is there a way to just update or refresh the Line Chart with the $scope.dataFromREST data received and not create a new Chart object every time? (Because I think, the crash come from creating a new chart every time) I see the ".update()" function, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I have also tried the ".destroy()" and I am still getting the browser wind up to crash.

How can I get rid of that crash? Please help!

Comment: Let me know if my answer does not work for you.  It would be good to understand what sort of things you tried when you said the `update` function was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to simply update the underlying chart.js chart data without having to re-instantiate the chart each and every time.  You just need to use the [`update(duration, lazy)`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) function from the API.

Here is an example that I use in one of my apps (modified for your specific case).  Note, `chart` is my chart.js object (what was returned from `new Chart()...`:

```
assembledData = {};
assembledData.data = // data from api call in an acceptable data format that chart.js understands
assembledData.colors = // new color definition for your data so it will update correctly
assembledData.labels = // new label definition for your data so it will update correctly

chart.data.datasets[0].data = assembledData.data;
chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = assembledData.colors;
chart.data.labels = assembledData.labels;
chart.update();
```

Depending on how your chart behaves you may not have to re-define `colors` and `labels` on each update.